# Why is the response different from the fetch post request?

Tags: javascript, rest, fetch-api

Why is my token undefined when i make a post request like this:

```
let requestInfo = JSON.stringify({
      email: email,
      password: password,
    });
let requestOptions = {
      method: "POST",
      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
      body: requestInfo
    }
fetch('http://url/token', requestOptions).then(response => {
        response.json()
        setShowLoading(false);
      }).then(token => console.log(token)).catch(error => console.log(error))
```

The token => console.log(token) is always undefined, and when i log in with the wrong credentials the .catch(error => console.log(error)) does not fire

but when i make the post request like this is works perfectly fine:

```
const response = await fetch('http://url/token', requestOptions);
      const data = await response.json();
      console.log(data);
```

Comment: .json() is an async task, control flow will pass to next line once its execution is started. so, either you use  "then" for promise fulfilled state or use await.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return `response.json()` inside the `then` clauses, in order to use it in the next `then` clause.

```
fetch('http://url/token', requestOptions).then(response => {
    setShowLoading(false);
    return response.json()
}).then(token => console.log(token)).catch(error => console.log(error))
```